# JUnit5 - customised lifecycle events/extension points

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

I am writing an acceptance test suite in Junit5. I'd like to generate customised output (html) specific to my domain as a result of this. This output will contain data that is obtained from lifecycle events such as test started (or before all tests) and also some data comes from non-lifecycle events - for example: in the middle of the execution of a test I'd like to emit some data that is also collected for reporting.

Can someone tell me how to do this? I am aware of [custom listeners](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-listeners) and [extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration) which are all good for lifecycle events however it is not easy to add some non-lifecycle data in the middle of test execution around this?

Comment: Already looked at TestReporter? https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestReporter.html

Answer (score 0):

As [@johanneslink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76654803/junit5-customised-lifecycle-events-extension-points#comment135150817_76654803) already pointed out, you can use [`TestReporter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestReporter.html) "to publish *report entries* for the current container or test to the reporting infrastructure", also in the middle of a test execution:

```java
class TestReporterDemo {

    @Test
    void reportSingleValue(TestReporter testReporter) {
        testReporter.publishEntry("a status message");
    }

    @Test
    void reportKeyValuePair(TestReporter testReporter) {
        testReporter.publishEntry("a key", "a value");
    }

    @Test
    void reportMultipleKeyValuePairs(TestReporter testReporter) {
        Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("user name", "dk38");
        values.put("award year", "1974");

        testReporter.publishEntry(values);
    }

}
```

Or you create a custom [`ParamterResolver`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ParameterResolver.html) for your own reporter/extension implementation. See also: ["Dependency Injection for Constructors and Methods"](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection).